# Convert R plotting commands into loop for many files

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

Currently I have been using R to read in a table and plot some of the data which I save as a png file. Now I have 100 files and would like this process to be automated rather than manually changing the path 100 times.

Additionally I would like to join the 100 files into one table in R that I can subsequently analyse. The join would be in the format of dplyr's bind_rows as all files have the same column headers. I've done this for when I have two tables in R but now when I am using a loop to read files in sequentially. What would be the best way to do this in R? Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

```
my_data <- read.table('/path/to/data/results/sample_1.txt', header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

ggplot(my data, aes(x=alt_freq)) + geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white", bins = 20) + xlim(c(0,1))

ggsave("/path/to/plots/sample_1.png", plot = last_plot(),width = 16, height = 9)

#append table to one large table in the format of dplyr::bind_rows(y, z)
```

Input files are all named with the same naming convention:

```
sample_1.txt
sample_2.txt
sample_3.txt
```

The files look like:

```
sample_name position    alt_freq    ref_freq    sample_1_counts
sample 1    10  0.5 0.5 2
sample 1    20  0.25    0.75    4
```

All txt files are in the same directory and all txt files are of interest.

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory? And are all the `.txt` files in that directory of interest?

Comment: Yes and yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First collect the complete path of the files of interest

```
library(ggplot2)
all_files <- list.files("/path/to/data/results", pattern = "sample_\\d+\\.txt$", 
             full.names = TRUE)
```

Then create a function to apply to each file

```
new_fun <- function(path_of_file) {
  my_data <- read.table(path_of_file, header = TRUE)

  ggplot(my_data, aes(x=alt_freq)) + 
   geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white", bins = 20) + xlim(c(0,1))

  ggsave(paste0(dirname(path_of_file), "/", sub("txt$", "png", 
  basename(path_of_file))), plot = last_plot(),width = 16, height = 9)
}
```

We use `paste0` to create path to save the plot dynamically by getting the directory name and replacing the ending `txt` with `png`.

Then use `lapply`/`map`/`for` loop to apply `new_fun` to each file

```
lapply(all_files, new_fun)
```

---

To combine all the files into one dataframe we can do

```
combined_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_files, read.table, header = TRUE))
```

If the header is different for one column we can change the column name for that particular column and then `rbind`. So for example, if the header information for column 1 is different, we can do

```
combined_data  <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_files, function(x) {
   df <- read.table(x, header = TRUE)
   names(df)[1] <- "new_header"
   df$filename <- basename(x)
   df
}))
```

Comment: This works perfectly except I discovered one of the column names in each file contains the sample name. So rbind fails because not all column names match. However the column order is the same across files. Is there a way to combine the files ignoring this variation in column name and just keeping the header from the first file? Or ignoring headers completely and I will add a header afterwards?

Comment: @user964689 I have updated the last part in the answer, you can change the column number based on your actual data (I have used 1 here).  It should work now.

Comment: perfect thanks. This should probably be a new question but if you don't mind, would there be a way to add the file name as a column so when I merge all the files I can see which rows belong to which sample? Usually I'd use dplyr's mutate to make a new column with the sample name as a string but would be fantastic to automate to do this for each file as they are merged. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user964689 yes, updated the answer. Added a new column called `filename` which holds the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following.

Change these to their real values.

```
in_dir <- '/path/to/data/results'
out_dir <- '/path/to/plots'
```

Now the plots and binding the tables.

```
library(ggplot2)

old_dir <- getwd()
setwd(in_dir)

flnames <- list.files(pattern = '^sample_[[:digit:]]+\\.txt$')
data_list <- lapply(flnames, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = '\t')

lapply(seq_along(data_list), function(i){
  ggplot(data_list[[i]], aes(x = alt_freq)) + 
    geom_histogram(color = "black", fill = "white", bins = 20) + 
    xlim(c(0, 1))
  f <- sub('txt$', 'png', flname[i])
  outfile <- paste(out_dir, f, sep = '/')
  ggsave(outfile, plot = last_plot(),width = 16, height = 9)
})

data_all <- dplyr::bind_rows(data_list)
```

Final cleanup.

```
setwd(old_dir)

## NOT RUN
#rm(data_list)
```